# How do I add a custom propperty on a button and retrieve it when clicked in android?

Tags: android, button, attributes

I have a couple buttons that are hard coded that will need to store some specific data and provide that attribute when clicked such as, one button is "non-fiction" and the other "fiction". I need to use an attribute and not the button text since the button text may change down the line but the attribute is need for database calls.

That is, "non-fiction" could become "true stories" but "non-fiction" will still need to be returned.

I've done something similar programmatically with btn.setTag(...) and btn.getTag(...) but those buttons are generated based on the database not hard coded into the app.

How do I set a custom attribute to a button then retrieve it?

something like:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/fictionButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="showTools"
android:text="@string/fiction_button"
custom:bookType="fiction" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/nonfictionButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="showTools"
android:text="@string/non_fiction_button"
custom:bookType="nonfiction" />
```

----- edit -----

I've changed my approach based on the answer so far.

I've set before the onCreate:

```
Button fictionButton;
Button nonfictionButton;
```

Inside the onCreate I've placed:

```
fictionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fictionButton);
nonfictionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nonfictionButton);

fictionButton.setTag("bookType","Fiction");
nonfictionButton.setTag("bookType", "Non Fiction");
```

when the button is clicked I'm getting the tag and storing to a SharedPreference

However now I'm getting an error at `fictionButton.setType("bookType","Fiction");` ADT doesn't like the key and wants to remove it.

----- edit -----

The set tag is working but now the getTag is throwing the NullPointerException. I'm using `Button b` to target all buttons and attempting to get the tag when any button is clicked inside the onClick event. buttonID is initialized before the onCreate and declared as `R.id.fictionButton` in the onCreate:

```
b = (Button) view;
String buttonText = b.getTag(buttonID).toString();
```

----- edit -----

my java file before and with the onCreate:

```
public class Crossroads extends baseActivity {

    FlyOutContainer root;

    Button b;
    Button fictionButton;
    Button nonfictionButton;
    Integer buttonID;

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "myPrefs";
    SharedPreferences storedInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.root = (FlyOutContainer) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.activity_crossroads, null);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crossroads);

        buttonID = R.id.fictionButton;

        fictionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fictionButton);
        nonfictionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nonfictionButton);

        fictionButton.setTag(buttonID,"Fiction");
        nonfictionButton.setTag(buttonID,"Non Ficiton");

        this.setContentView(root);
    }
...
}
```

----- edit -----

Fixed the final piece by comparing ids and setting the string accordingly:

```
Integer viewId = view.getId();
        String buttonText;
//      setContentView(R.layout.activity_crossroads);
        if(viewId == R.id.fictionButton )
            buttonText = fictionButton.getTag(buttonID).toString();
        else
            buttonText = nonfictionButton.getTag(buttonID).toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your main problem is that you app won't compile
because you have written:

```
setTag(String, String);
```

but the `setTag(..)` function doesn't take an `String` as key but an `int`
so you could do like this:

```
public static int KEY_BOOK_TYPE = 0; //some int

fictionButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fictionButton);
nonfictionButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nonfictionButton);

fictionButton.setTag(KEY_BOOK_TYPE, "Fiction");
nonfictionButton.setTag(KEY_BOOK_TYPE, "Non Fiction");
```

`setType(String, String)` doesn't exist in `Button` and so ADT wants to remove that line

***--- edit ---***
be careful and call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

before calling any `findViewById(R.id.something)` else it `returns null`

***--- edit ---***
if you call `setTag(...)` with the button id too, thats really good idea!
but you cannot simply cast any view to the button you want

you have to save the button you got from `findViewById` like this:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    int non_fiction_id;
    int fiction_id;

    Button button_non_fiction;
    Button button_fiction;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        non_fiction_id = R.id.button_non_fiction;
        fiction_id = R.id.button_fiction;

        button_non_fiction = (Button)findViewById(non_fiction_id);
        button_fiction = (Button)findViewById(fiction_id);
    }

    void SomeOtherPlace()
    {
        String non_ficiton_tag = button_non_fiction.getTag(non_fiction_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: so really the same way I'm doing it when I create a button programmatically just do "Button btn = (Button) find..." and set the tag there.

Comment: oh im sorry i've overread that. i'll look for another way and update my answer

Comment: @dcp3450 i don't really understand whats your problem then.  you could set the tag if you create the view and retrieve it when you need it

Comment: no problem, could you post a bit of your main Activity? the `onCreate()` function (if this is the place where you show the buttons)

Comment: I've updated my questions after taking your suggestions. I'm getting an error at the setTag now though.

Comment: @dcp3450 i think you wanted to write `setTag` not `setType` see my edits in my answer

Comment: I missed typed. I'm using "setTag" in the app

Comment: @dcp3450 you missed it at the end again, but i know your problem now **really** and will post a solution now

Comment: now that I look deeper (closer) the error is "The method setTag(int, Object) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)" looks like setTag won't accept a string as a key...

Comment: right, ill just write it into my answer so others can learn too

Comment: @dcp3450 which function exactly?

Comment: The setTags. It's like it can't find the button in the activity.

Comment: @dcp3450 have you called `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_layout);` in your `onCreate()` before the `findViewById` calls?

Comment: setContentView is called at the end of onCreate

Comment: you have to call it before calling `findViewById` because android has to know from which view you want to find them. youst move the line to the top (or at least before findView...)

Comment: I got passed that part. Turns out one issue was android didn't like me setting the id. It wanted an application created id so I used "buttonID = R.id.fictionButton" and it like that. Now I'm getting an error at the getTag method. NullPointerException again. I'll update my question.

Comment: I've updated the question with the newest "developments". (see what I did there?)

Comment: @dcp3450 updated my answer, see what i mean? declare the buttons outside onCreate so you can access them from everywhere

Comment: Updated the question to show my java file before and with the onCreate